# Hidden Facebook Birthdays

Tags: facebook

I used to be able to see my friends' birthdays on one of the side panels on the Facebook homepage, but now it's gone and I can't find a setting to bring it back. Is there such a setting? And if yes, where can I find it? And I know there are birthdays because it shows in my timeline from other people posting.

Answer (score 1):

From the Help Center:

> **How do I see my friends' upcoming birthdays?**
>
> To view upcoming birthdays, click **Events** in the left column of your homepage. You can also click on any event in the top right of your homepage and then click **See All**.
>
> - From calendar view, your friends' profile pictures mark their birthdays.
> - From list view, birthdays appear in chronological order as you scroll through your events.

Here is the direct link to see Today's Birthdays and Upcoming Birthdays:
https://www.facebook.com/events/birthdays